# Result json object not as expected with spray-json

Tags: json, scala, spray

I have model like this to parse result from db to json at rest api with akka-http

```
case class Category(id: Long,
                    title: String,
                    slug: String,
                    image: String,
                    parentId: Long,
                    createdAt: Timestamp) extends BaseEntity

object Category extends DefaultJsonProtocol with SprayJsonSupport {

  implicit object TimestampFormat extends RootJsonFormat[Timestamp] {
    val format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")

    def write(obj: Timestamp) = JsString(format.format(obj.getTime))

    def read(json: JsValue) = json match {
      case JsString(s) => new Timestamp(format.parse(s).getTime)
      case _ => throw DeserializationException("Date expected")
    }
  }

  implicit object ObjectJsonFormat extends RootJsonFormat[Category] {
    val format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")

    def write(obj: Category) = JsObject(Map(
      "id" -> JsNumber(obj.id),
      "title" -> JsString(obj.title),
      "slug" -> JsString(obj.slug),
      "image" -> JsString(obj.image),
      "parentId" -> JsNumber(obj.parentId),
      "createdAt" -> JsString(format.format(obj.createdAt.getTime))
    ))

    def read(value: JsValue): Category = value.convertTo[Category]
  }

  implicit val objectFormat = jsonFormat6(Category.apply)
}

case class CategoryResponse(status: Int, result: Category)

object CategoryResponse extends DefaultJsonProtocol with SprayJsonSupport {
  implicit val objectFormat = jsonFormat2(CategoryResponse.apply)
}
```

but position member at json object not same like position at case class if case class have member more than 4. The result just like this

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "result": {
    "image": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-Fq_uiT7y10k/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/YzIf8sfr7sI/s88-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg",
    "slug": "news",
    "id": 3,
    "createdAt": "2016-11-23 14:09:45",
    "title": "news",
    "parentId": 1
  }
}
```

How to set position member json object just like this

```
{
      "status": 1,
      "result": {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "news",
        "slug": "news",
        "image": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-Fq_uiT7y10k/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/YzIf8sfr7sI/s88-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg",
        "parentId": 1,
        "createdAt": "2016-11-23 14:09:45"
      }
    }
```

Comment: 1) You can't do it. 2) You don't need to do it because json parser should parse it regardless of order of properties.

Comment: @expert but why json-spray do that if member of model more than 4 because i prefer like fix position just as my model so every api that my machine produce have consistence structure

Comment: json specification doesn't require particular order of properties therefore spray-json uses whatever its author picked driven perhaps by rationale of performance. Why do you need to maintain the order ? Is it cosmetic requirement or is it requirement of person who will be consuming your json ?

Comment: @expert just for cosmetic. There is first time i found this issue previously when using jackson, gson or another json parser my service always produce same result position as my model... i use json-spray because that lib under akka-http... maybe someone else have same issue and found tricky so i can get result as i expected....

Comment: I see. Well, I know it's not what you wanted to hear but don't bother with it :)

Comment: @expert okay thanks for your advice